# How do I search for a service with a specific external ip using kubectl

Tags: ip, kubectl

I am trying to find which service has a specific external ip in k8s. At the moment I am using `kubectl get svc --all-namespaces | grep $external_ip`, but I would like to be able to do this purely in kubectl. It doesn't appear as if I can use field-selectors. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good guide [JSONPath support](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/)

Try:

```sh
IP="[[YOUR-EXTERNAL-IP]]"
JP="{.items[?(@.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip==\"${IP}\")].metadata.name}"

kubectl get services \
--all-namespaces \
--output=jsonpath="${JP}"
```

This queries the `items` list returned for entries that contain `status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip` with a value matching `${IP}` and returns the `items`'s `metadata.name`

Comment: ```k get svc --all-namespaces -o=jsonpath="{.items[?(@.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip==\"$IP\")].metadata.name}"``` thats nice and I could use it as a oneliner